# With CLion, how do I set an environment variable for the Makefile build?

Tags: makefile, clion

```
I want setup a C preoject built by makefile on Clion 2023.1.5. This project depend on enviroment varibles written into a env.sh file. So Clion have to soure the env.sh file first, then run make to build. 

I am not make sure how to source env.sh before running make in Clion. 
I aslo config the "Pre-configuration commands executed to generate the Makefile" like following picture, BUT also not works.

How can I source env.sh before running make in Clion?
```

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcOgd.png)

I aslo config the "Pre-configuration commands executed to generate the Makefile" like following picture, BUT also not works.

Comment: I don't know about CLion, but why are you even structuring things as you describe?  `make` *does* expose environment variables as `make` variables, and does, by default, give those precedence over definitions in the makefile, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to rely on that.  Put your variable definitions -- or at least defaults -- directly into the makefile.

Comment: I port a old project which use env.sh setup enviroment at frist. I dont want change any configue due to co-work with others.

Answer (score 1):

You can add environment file from Toolchain. And this file will execute before Build.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmlls.png)